# Counter in Variable Selection

Tags: r

I am running the following code, which is working fine:

```
model <- NULL 
summary <- NULL 
stepwise <- NULL 
for (i in 1:100){
model[[i]] <- lm(r[[i]]~x1[[i]]+x2[[i]]+x3[[i]]+noise1[[i]]+noise2[[i]]+noise3[[i]]+noise4[[i]]+noise5[[i]]+noise6[[i]]+noise7[[i]])
summary[[i]] <- summary(model[[i]])$coefficients 
stepwise[[i]] <- step(model[[i]], direction="both")$coefficients 
}
```

I wanted to set up a counter to keep track of the variables that are stored in the stepwise list. I want a count of how many times each variable (x1, x2, x3, noise1, noise2, noise3, noise4, noise5, noise6, noise7) occurs. I was thinking of something like this

```
createCounter <- function(VALUE){
  for (i in 1:100){ 
    output <- VALUE <- VALUE+i
    return(output)
  }
}
```

but I don't know how to fine-tune it so that R understands to count a value if the stepwise list contains the particular variable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could just do `table(stepwise)` or might have to do `lapply(stepwise,table)`

Comment: Your function, as written, will exit (`return`) after the first iteration. I assume you want to have `output[i] <- VALUE <- VALUE+i` and then `return(output)` outside the `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the step()$coefficients returns a named vector of the coefficients. While the values contain the actual coefficients, the names on the vector store the actual names of the variables. So you can extract and count all the variable names from all the 100 models with

```
table(unlist(lapply(stepwise, function(x) names(x))))
```

Comment: Ah I see! I was having trouble extracting the names, so I tried $coefficients. This makes sense since you are applying a function to a list - hence, lapply. Stepwise is the list you are applying lapply to and then you are extracting the names with names(x) and of course you are tabling everything to get the counts. Thanks, the line of code you provided makes perfect sense!